# Lucene.net: Separate building Index from Searching the Index

Tags: asp.net, lucene.net

I created a website but i have a problem.
i want to build **once** an index und use it.

at the moment i have two functions "create a document an store it into the directory" and "searching"

when the user submit:

```
sub submit ()
    create_doc()
    search(text) 
end sub
```

this works, but when i try this:

```
create_doc()
sub submit()
   search(text)
end sub
```

it's like the directory has been deleted.

```
global:
Dim analyzer As StandardAnalyzer = New StandardAnalyzer()Dim directory As Directory = FSDirectory.GetDirectory("C:\[...]luceneindex", True)
Dim indexwriter As IndexWriter = New IndexWriter(directory, analyzer, True)

Sub create_doc()
    Dim meindoc As New Document()
    im feldbodytext As Field = New Field("bodytext", textstring[...]
    meindoc.Add(feldbodytext)
    indexwriter.AddDocument(meindoc)
    indexwriter.Close()
end sub

Sub lucene_search(ByVal strSuchbegriff As String)
    Dim parser As QueryParser = New QueryParser("bodytext", analyzer)
    Dim query As Query = parser.Parse(strSuchbegriff)
    Dim hits As Hits = searcher.Search(query)
    [...]
end sub
```

Is there a possibility to store the index permanently?
could there be a problem init. the index writer gloabel, but close it local?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is that each time you declare your `IndexWriter`, the index is being re-created and the contents of the index erased - this is because of the 3rd parameter being passed into the constructor (`True`):

```
Dim indexwriter As IndexWriter = New IndexWriter(directory, analyzer, True)
```

You should instead use `False`, to indicate that the existing contents of the index should remain unchanged:

```
Dim indexwriter As IndexWriter = New IndexWriter(directory, analyzer, False)
```

Comment: hello, thank your for yor answer,
by using Dim indexwriter As IndexWriter = New IndexWriter(directory, analyzer, False)
i encounter an error "source can't be found"

and it even doesn't find anything when i'm indexing the first time,
when i put both functions in one other function he finds an index.

could it be the directory? :
Dim directory As Directory = FSDirectory.GetDirectory("C:\Dok[...]\luceneindex", True)

Answer (score 0):

ahh, i think i've got it ;-)

the first time i create a index i have to use

```
Dim directory As Directory = FSDirectory.GetDirectory("C:\[...]\luceneindex", True)
Dim indexwriter As IndexWriter = New IndexWriter("C:\[...]luceneindex", analyzer, True)
```

and after indexing i have to use both with "False".

True everytimes creates an index?
thanks =)

Comment: Yes - you need to use that the first time you create the index, then from that point on you use False to indicate you are adding to an existing index.